# Redis - What data type to use to Store User Active

Tags: php, redis

I'm new to Redis, i'm switching from memcached.

I want to store a value for each users that will update every 5 seconds. The value being a heartbeat that is basically the user id 'eg: 1000000' and a datetype stamp '2014-06-06 10:41:10'.

What advise would you have around the datatype to store this as?

I've looked at : http://redis.io/topics/data-types and it appears a String would make most sense.

Therefore just "APPEND key value".

```
APPEND 1000000_active unixdatetime
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Does the APPEND overwrite the previous append?

Is there anything I should be aware of? Note: the data doesn't need to be persistent.

Thank You

Comment: If you look at the documentation you will see that APPEND appends the value : http://redis.io/commands/append Why don't you do it with the redis php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APPEND does not overwrite previous value.

BTW why do you want to use APPEND here ? Don't you need to overwrite the key value with the last time stamp each time?

In case you need to overwrite, you can simply use "SET key value" which will update your key every time.